# Using mssql_close() before mssq_fetch_array()

Tags: php, sql-server, performance, database-connection

We are developing a script that reads data from a SQL Server 2005 located in other server.

At this moment we are having some trouble with the connection time, because the data we are retrieving is rather large.

One solution that came to us was calling mssql_close() just after mssql_query() and before mssql_fetch_array(), because after mssql_query() the data is on our PHP server, or that is what the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) says. That would shorten the connection time quite a bit because of the data manipulations we have to do on the returned records.

Is that possible? Do we need to have an open connection for executing mssql_fetch_array()?

Comment: Why dont you test it?

Comment: We just can't at this moment. We are waiting to get access to the database and we need to come up with solutions in the meantime. There isn't much information about it on the Internet, so that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large data set to be pulled you can either:

1. Pull the data in chunks (multiple requests to DB)
2. Increase the timeout connection (if DB is under your control)

I also hope you have read this part from the manual:

> The downside of the buffered mode is that larger result sets might require quite a lot memory. The memory will be kept occupied till all references to the result set are unset or the result set was explicitly freed, which will automatically happen during request end the latest.

For the question:

> Do we need to have an open connection for executing mssql_fetch_array()?

Not needed if you have already fetched data.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The amount of data stored in our server is not a problem right now, so we will use the buffered connection.